# Отладка, перехват ошибок в mysql (php?)

Tags: php, mysqli, отладка, логирование, обработка-ошибок

```
$q = 'select usname,regdate_usopt,usplace,usablog,uslife,umk,usfoto,usdes,uslevel,usoffst,lact from usopt join act on uid_usopt=uid_act where uid_usopt=?';
$rawdata = mysqli_prepare($ddb, $q);

//qres('prep', $rawdata, $ddb);

$res = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($rawdata, 'di', $uid);
  $err=mysqli_error($ddb);
  echo "mysqli_error = $err<br>";
  exit;
```

$err=mysqli_error($ddb); возвращеет пустую строку. Но ошибка есть.
[image: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in...]

---

```
$q = 'select usname,regdate_usopt,usplace,usablog,uslife,umk,usfoto,usdes,uslevel,usoffst,lact from usopt join act on uid_usopt=uid_act where uid_usopt=?';
$rawdata = mysqli_prepare($ddb, $q);
//qres('prep', $rawdata, $ddb);

$res = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($rawdata, 'di', $uid);
  //$err=mysqli_error($ddb);
  //echo "mysqli_error = $err<br>";
  //exit;

$q = 'show warnings';
$sq_data = mysqli_query($ddb, $q);  //SimpleQuery_data
//var_dump($sq_data);

$x = mysqli_num_rows($sq_data);
$data = mysqli_fetch_row($sq_data); //SimpleQuery_data
echo 'show warnings dump<br>';
        var_dump($data);

    exit;
```

$q = 'show warnings'; и последующая обработка возвращают NULL
[image: show warnings dump /var/www/html/user.php:94:null]

Как получить сообщение об ошибке в переменную? И почему show warnings и mysqli_error($ddb); "не работают"?

Comment: Намного лучше использовать PDO и ловить PDOException с помощью try-catch

Comment: ilyaplot, намного лучше не писать кривых запросов и тогда нечего будет ловить.

Comment: В общем случае при запросе к базе не должно быть ворнигов. Если они есть значит нужно подумать как сделать чтобы их не было,а писать в логи только для отладки разве что.

Comment: для отладки нужно чтобы в рабочем базе и коде все было хорошо. А сецчас варинг модетт быть изза обрезки или несответвсвия полей в тбл и данных. такое нужно ловить.

Comment: уже все понимаю: это синтаксические ошибки. И сейчас иногда такие проскакивают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqli_error($ddb); возвращет видимо ошибки, если есть, в mysql запросе. У вас же ошибки на уровне сборки запроса. И если вы его исправите проблема решится. Но отвечу на вопрос как перехватить ошибки:

```
set_error_handler("MyClass::myWarning_handler", E_WARNING | E_STRICT);

//тут ваш код кот вызывает ошибки

//вернуться к состяюнию по умолчанию
restore_error_handler();
```

...

```
    //confGeneral::PATH_LOG - переменная кот хранит путь к логам
    //$errstr -это ваша ошибка в переменной
    function myWarning_handler($errno, $errstr) {
            if (!is_dir(confGeneral::PATH_LOG)) {
                mkdir(confGeneral::PATH_LOG, 0777, true);
            }
            $filename = "mailErrors.log";

            error_log(date('d/m/Y H:i:s') . " WARNING : " . $errstr . PHP_EOL, 3, confGeneral::PATH_LOG.$filename);
        }
```

Comment: ага, в qres('prep', $rawdata, $ddb);  получается получить строку с описанием ошибки. Конкретно в коде выше я спец допустил ошибку. Щас почитаю об http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php и протестирую как оно будет.

Comment: уже дошло, Теперь нужно найти список ошибок по номерам. Наверное решено! http://php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.constants.php